# Run statetments only when all try statements were successful in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

I am trying to do sth like this:

```py
try:
  database_insert_1()  # insert sth to table_1
  database_insert_2()  # insert sth to table_2
except Exception as e:
  print(e.message)
```

I expect `database_insert_1` and `database_insert_2` only be executed when both of them could be run successfully.

The way I am doing it above will a problem that, `database_insert_1` will still be executed successfully in case of having only `database_insert_2` failing.

The use case is that the two tables share a same schema and I expect the two table to be consistant and don't want to have only one of them get updated.

How can I solve above problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Do they execute on the same database? If so the solution is to use a database transaction.

Comment: @AlexHall Yeah, that will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

So for example if you using sql database then pass the cursor in your function and don't commit inside the insert function

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    database_insert_1(cursor)  # insert sth to table_1
    database_insert_2(cursor)  # insert sth to table_2
    cursor.commit

except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
```

So if you have error in either of the function then it will jump to exception and it wont update any of the databases.

Comment: Yes, this is an easier solution. I previous had two `commit` inside of the two `database_insert_fn`s, which make things troublesome. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could slightly modify your code and it will work, need to make it more hierarchical:

```
try:
  try:
     database_insert_1()  # insert sth to table_1
     database_insert_2()  # insert sth to table_2
  except:
      pass
except Exception as e::  
print(e.message)
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't work. Tanmay or Alex 's answer will do.